# I must create a function, that returns the last element of an array that is passed in

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am lost on how to use an array in a function. Here is what I have but it is not a function so it is incorrect?

```
var theLastOne = [1,2,3,4,5,'purple'];
var last_element = theLastOne[theLastOne.length - 1];
    console.log(last_element)
```

Here is the exact question. Create a function called theLastOne that returns the last element of an array that is passed in. Hint: This should work for an array of any size.

Comment: The above is correct, add a function header at the top, followed by { and a return statement followed by }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like others have said, you just needed to reformat, but you can do something like this: Same as others, just explaining it a bit more.

```
// here is your array
var arrayExample = [3,4,5,'hello','whatever']

// here is your function - see that 'arr', that is the array you will 
// pass in. The reference your function will use to access 
// the passed in array. It is an 'argument'
function theLastOne(arr) {
   return arr[arr.length - 1];
}

    // call it like this
    console.log(theLastOne(arrayExample))

   // or like this
    console.log(theLastOne([3,4,5,'hello','whatever']))
```

Either pass in an array (2nd example) explicitly.. its there, right there as you pass it in.

OR

pass it in as a reference, first example.

note: I am using console.log so you can see the output in your developer console. In real code, you would not include it. You can also "alert" instead of using console.log

Answer (score 1):

When writing a function, think about your inputs and outputs. You want a **function** that accepts an **array** as an argument, and **returns the last element**

So something like this

```
function theLastOne(array) {
  var lastElement = /* somehow get it from the passed array parameter */;

  return lastElement;
}
```

You already know how to "somehow get it from the passed array", you have it in your example :)

Comment: I may be more confused now, where would the elements of the array be placed?

Comment: Same as you show in your code above: `array[array.length-1]`

Answer (score -2):

This Code will help !!!

```
function lastElement(last){
    var lastelement = last[last.length - 1];
    while(last.length === 0){
        return null;
    }
    
    return lastelement;


}
lastElement([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Why the while loop? How will this code help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).